# O Matlab possibilita exportação de dados de maneira interativa (tempo real)?

Tags: matlab, gráfico, exportação, entrada-de-dados

Boa tarde, estou utilizando o matlab de maneira a receber dados via HTML em tempo real para gerar gráficos que se atualizam constantemente, mas ainda não encontrei em lugar algum como eu poderia exportar esses graficos para outras aplicações em tempo real (e é que existe essa possibilidade). A unica informação que encontrei a respeito seria em como transformar os gráficos em arquivos externos mas então eles se tornariam estáticos. Caso alguém saiba informar a respeito eu ficaria extremamente grato.

Comment: Tentei dar uma olhada, mas não encontrei nada logo de cara. Matlab tem o "live scripts" mas não tenho certeza se é possivel uma integracão com o html. https://plot.ly/matlab/   parece ter uma opcão para fazer isso, mas talvez não seja tão simples tb.

Comment: Entendi. muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma função que fica em loop, sempre pegando o valor ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/87466-real-time-plot-from-streaming-data)).

Você pode ainda criar uma classe e adicionar evento e listener ([link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/learning-to-use-events-and-listeners.html)).
Mas talvez seja mais complexo que a primeira.

Para integrações com outras linguagens e que você possa usar na Web, dá uma olhada no MATLAB Compiler e MATLAB Compiler SDK.

Você pode ainda fazer o contrário, embarcar o HTML no MATLAB e tratar pelo AppDesigner. Veja se [isso](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uihtml.html) ajuda.